# Navbar not responsive with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im using a code found on the internet for a navbar using bootstrap. I like it I find it beautiful. However when I resize my screen I can watch that this is not responsive. Links disappears and it makes something strange.

Here is the code of the navbar :

```css
.navbar-new-top{
    background: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand{
    font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    width: 20%;
}
.navbar-new-top ul{
    margin-right: 9%;
}
.navbar-new-top ul li{
    margin-right: 8%;
}
.navbar-new-bottom{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin-top: 4%;
    height: 40px;
}
.navbar-new-bottom ul li{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item a:hover{
    color: #0062cc;
}
.dropdown-menu.show{
    background: #f8f9fa;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.header-btn{
    width: 161%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 8%;
    background: #0062cc;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md flex-nowrap navbar-new-top">
            <a href="https://www.adopteunvpn.com/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="#" alt=""/>adopteunvpn.com</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
<?php echo 'Votre adresse IP : &#x274C; ' . getIp(); ?>
                           <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <button type="button"  class="header-btn">Button</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-new-bottom">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pt-2 pt-md-0" id="navbar2">

                <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center px-3">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a  href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I included bootstrap 4 in header.

Can you explain to me whats wrong ? Im very new to css.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline;` for Li tag  check code above :

```
.nav_display{

    display: inline;
}
```

You sould to add this class to Li Tag on ur nav bar :

```
<ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center px-3" style=" list-style-type: none;">
                    <li class="nav-item nav_display active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav_display">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav_display">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav_display">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav_display">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav_display">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Also for responsive remove this css   `width: 161%;` on `.header-btn`
also remove this class  `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse pt-2 pt-md-0" id="navbar2">` let just the `id`

Comment: I tried this but this is exactly the same result. When resinzing window, header and menu are mixing themseleves and link disappears...

Comment: the issue was on that class "navbar-collapse collapse pt-2 pt-md-0" remove it and use the .nav_display class same for width on header-btn

Comment: HamzaNig, thank you but look at what I got when I resize my Window : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2021/04/5/1611915808-capture-du-2021-01-29-11-22-33.png

Comment: its could be from the fixed-top class , but u can try to add style="margin-top:5%" on nav tag that containe the ul list

Comment: like this <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-md navbar-new-bottom" style="margin-top:5%">

Comment: I did this but when resizing windows, ul-li links are going to left of screen, not on the navbar ! I dont understand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227999/discussion-between-lien-lien-and-hamzanig).